# truncate characters in a HTML element - Django Templates

Tags: django, templates, truncate

In my django templates i have a list of objects which is rendered as follows:

```
<li class="keys">
{% for key in job.key_list|slice:":2" %}
    {% if not forloop.last %}
        <a href="/keys/{{ key.id }}/{{ key }}/">{{ key }}</a>,
    {% else %}
        <a href="/keys/{{ key.id }}/{{ key }}/">{{ key }}</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</li>
```

This outputs the list as:

```
some_key, some_key_two
```

I want to truncate the number of characters to 20 **but on the whole list**. So that it renders something like:

```
some_key, some_key_t...
```

I am aware about the `truncatechars` and `truncatewords` filters available in django but they work on a string variable within the template.

How do i go about implementing this functionality ?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're after. Do you want to truncate the `key` in the href part of the `<a>` or the `key` in the text of the `<a>` ?

Comment: i do not want to truncate a single object, For example: if i use `truncatechars` to 6 chars on elements say (Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange) it will output. `Stack ..., Stack ...`. I want to truncate the characters in the rendered list so that if i truncate on 20 characters it looks like `Stack Overflow, Stac...`. So here the total number of characters shown within the `<li>` element is 20.

Comment: Don't think django can help you here. Try to do that through CSS by specifying `max-width` and `overflow: hidden`. Or format the strings in view and pass them in list to template.

Comment: @Rohan: Yeah I thought so, maybe an easier solution would be to use a jquery plugin like expander.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, that's a strange requirement. You would have to implement this as a template tag or custom filter that takes a list and transforms it.

```
@register.filter(name='truncatinator')
def truncatinator(value, arg):
    strings = ",".join(value)
    if len(strings) >= arg:
        part = strings[0:19] + "..."
    return part.split(',')
```

and use it like this `{% for object in job.key_list|truncatinator:"20" %}`

What you will notice though is that you will loop over a string list here instead of your objects which will give you this disadvantage: You won't have access to your `.id`.
This could be modified though as well.

I would do this with Javascript instead but I don't think that Django should be responsible for this overall.

Comment: would writing a tag instead of a filter be a better idea ?

Comment: @Amyth I don't know actually but I made a small javascript for you. I based it on jquery. Why? I don't know. Here ya go anyways: http://jsfiddle.net/sNEPA/2/ - It's not great since it uses global variables but you could hide it in a function and be done with it.